# searching through entire database php script

Tags: php

```
$tableArray = array('tbl_course','tbl_faculty');
  if(!empty($_POST["searchField"]))
    {
        $search=$_POST["searchField"];
        foreach( $tableArray as $tblArry)   
        {
           $out .= $tblArry.";";
            $sql_search = "select * from ".$tblArry." where ";
            $sql_search_fields = Array();
            $sql2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$tblArry;
            $rs2 =mysql_query($sql2);
            if(mysql_num_rows($rs2)>0){
                while($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2)){
                    $colum = $r2[0];
                    $sql_search_fields[] = $colum." like('%".$search."%')";
                }
            }
            $sql_search .= implode(" OR ", $sql_search_fields);
            $rs3 = mysql_query($sql_search);

        }
    }
```

The problem is I want to display results from the database. The script is looping through columns of 2 tables and is creating a SQL statement based on that.

The only problem I am facing is how can I fetch data from the resultset r3?

Comment: This sounds like a question better suited to Stack Overflow as it appears to be programming the PHP after running the query, rather than the SQL itself

Comment: You should always avoid recursively querying on a database whenever possible.  The 3 tables should likely be joined in a single query to get your data.  Can you describe your 3 tables better, what data you hope to show from them, and what criteria need to be applied to the query.